# Entity Framework 4.1 : The navigation property configured with One-to-One/zero mapping

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework 4.1 : The navigation property ‘BusinessUser’ declared on type ‘Login’ has been configured with conflicting multiplicities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772149/entity-framework-4-1-the-navigation-property-businessuser-declared-on-type)

I am having two entities

```
BusinessUser { Id(PK), Name,...}

Login { BusinessUserID(PK, FK), Email, Password, etc...}
```

Relationship between `BusinessUser` and `Login` is **one-to-zero/one**.

I am having following configurations
In BusinessUser EF configuration class

```
this.HasOptional(bu => bu.LoginInfo)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(l => l.BusinessUser);
```

In Login EF configuration class

```
this.HasRequired(l => l.BusinessUser)
    .WithOptional(bu => bu.LoginInfo);
```

I am getting following exception

> The navigation property 'BusinessUser' declared on type 'Login'  has been configured 
>   with conflicting multiplicities.

Where I am wrong with my one-to-one/zero configuration in EF 4.1 code first.

```
public class BusinessUser {
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual int BusinessID { get; set; }

    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }

    public Login LoginInfo { get; set; }
  }

 public class Login {
    public virtual int BusinessUserID { get; set; }

    public virtual string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public BUsinessUser BusinessUserInfo { get; set; }
  }
```

Also I am looking for bi-directional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the following mapping from `BusinessUser` configuration.

```
this.HasOptional(bu => bu.LoginInfo)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(l => l.BusinessUser);
```

Configuring the relationship in single configuration is enough. If you need to map it from `BusinessUser` configuration you can do it as follows.

```
this.HasOptional(bu => bu.LoginInfo)
    .WithRequired(l => l.BusinessUser);
```